# How do you create two identical arrays and change the values of just one?

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

What I am trying to do is create two arrays, which are identical. And when I change the value in the input field and click the button, I only want to change the value in the **second array**. However, when I do this, for some odd reason, it changes the value in **both arrays**? Any idea what I'm doing wrong?

Here is the simplified version of my code:

Javascript:

```
var arr1=[],

    arr2=[];

$(':input').each(function()
{
    var id = $(this).attr('id');

    arr1[id] = arr2[id] = {'text': $(this).val()};
});

$('#click').click(function()
{
    $(':input').each(function()
    {
        arr2[$(this).attr('id')].text = $(this).val();
    });

    alert(arr1['whatever'].text + '\n\n' + arr2['whatever'].text);

    return false;
});
```

HTML:

```
<input type="text" id="whatever" value="test">
<br><br>
<button type="button" id="click">Click</button>
```

**[Here is an example](http://jsfiddle.net/bbfxd/)**, i.e., when I change the value in the input field to `test2` and click the button, it shows me that it changed the value in both arrays.

If possible, I don't want to change the way I create those arrays, e.g. `arr[id] = {'text': $(this).val()}`. Unless that's where the problem lies.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're storing an *Object* in the *Arrays*

```
arr1[id] = arr2[id] = {'text': $(this).val()};
```

Objects are taken *ByRef*, not *ByVal*, so they aren't just equal, they're the same bit of memory, and changing one changes both. You probably want to make them like this;

```
var val = $(this).val();
arr1[id] = {'text': val};
arr2[id] = {'text': val};
```

Comment: It is pratically a dupe, but you added the thing about *Ref* and *Val*, so you have my +1

Comment: Thank you, that did it! And thanks for the explanation! :) I'll accept the answer, once the 8mins are over.

Answer (score 2):

Use `slice()`

```
var array2 = array1.slice(0);
```

Comment: I believe the first argument to `slice` is required, so `slice(0)`

Answer (score 2):

If you assign a double value to two different variables they will both have the same value, but when you change one you change the second too.

```
$(':input').each(function() {
    var id = $(this).attr('id'),
        val = $(this).val();
    arr1[id] = {'text': val};
    arr2[id] = {'text': val};
});
```

Comment: +1 for working solution but your text is only true for an _Object_, consider `a = b = 1; a = 0; b === 1; // true` and `a === b; // false`